# 'formDirective' is defined as an accessor in class 'ControlContainer', but is overridden here in 'ConnectArrayDirective' as an instance property

Tags: angular, redux, angular9, angular10, angular-redux

After updating angular 9 to the latest version ("@angular/core": "~11.0.0-next.0",). I got the below error, however, I have updated the latest version of `@angular-redux/form, @angular-redux/router and @angular-redux/store`

```
"@angular-redux/form": "^10.0.0",
"@angular-redux/router": "^10.0.0",
"@angular-redux/store": "^10.0.0",
```

## Angular update

```
"@angular/common": "~11.0.0-next.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~11.0.0-next.0",
"@angular/core": "~11.0.0-next.0",
"@angular/forms": "~11.0.0-next.0",
```

## Error

```
 ERROR in node_modules/@angular-redux/form/connect-array/connect-array.directive.d.ts:22:14 - error TS2610: 'formDirective' is defined as an accessor in class 'ControlContainer', but is overridden here in 'ConnectArrayDirective' as an instance property.

22     readonly formDirective: FormGroupDirective;
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular-redux/form/connect-array/connect-array.directive.d.ts:23:14 - error TS2610: 'path' is defined as an accessor in class 'ControlContainer', but is overridden here in 'ConnectArrayDirective' as an instance property.

23     readonly path: string[];
```

Answer (score 2):

These libraries are maintained no more, check [this repo](https://github.com/angular-redux/platform)

as a workaround while upgrading the project I set "skipLibCheck": true, in **tsconfig.json** inside compilerOptions like below:

```
{
  ...,
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...,
    ...,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    ...,
    ...
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    ...
  }
}
```